# What is the difference between readLine() and readlnOrNull() in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, input, kotlin-null-safety

As mentioned in Kotlin API document, [`readLine()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) returns the line read or `null` if end of file has already been reached but it is the same functionality as [`readlnOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln-or-null.html). So what is the difference here?

I know that `readlnOrNull()` and [`readln()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html) have been introduced in Kotlin 1.6 for the purpose of null safety but I can't understand why `readlnOrNull()` introduced when `readLine()` exist before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They added `readlnOrNull` as an alias of `readLine` for the sake of preserving the convention that each standard library function that throws a RuntimeException has an “orNull” version that returns null instead of throwing. It was added when `readln`was added. It’s so the matching function with this behavior can be easily found. If `readLn` had existed from the earliest version of Kotlin, then they might never have created a redundant `readLine` function that matches the behavior of `readlnOrNull`. They have not deprecated `readLine` because there’s nothing wrong with its behavior and it’s concise.

Comment: If you use `readLine`, then the current version of IntelliJ IDEA will recommend that you change it to `readlnOfNull`.

Answer (score 0):

readLine() and readlnOrNull() are both methods used in Kotlin for reading input from the user.

readLine() is used to read a line of text from the standard input and returns a string. If the user does not provide any input or an error occurs, this method throws an IOException.

```
scss

val input = readLine()
```

readlnOrNull() is similar to readLine(), but instead of throwing an exception, it returns null if the user does not provide any input or an error occurs.

```
scss

val input = readLine() ?: "No input provided"
```

In general, it is recommended to use readlnOrNull() as it provides a more flexible and safer way to handle input reading in Kotlin.

Comment: You’re mixing up `readLine` and `readln`. `readLine()` has identical functionality to `readlnOrNull()` and it does not throw an exception.